# Cannot add google account (It is not in the list of available account)

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, google-account, google-apps

I bought the tablets from China, and if I want to add Google account (from Settings.Account.AddAccount) ther is no google account in the list.. There is only

Corporate
IMAP
POP3

tablet:
x-302 of Dragon

h701

Android 4.4.2

kernel 3 April 67

Build ALPS.KK1.MP1.V2.11

and on tablet are no applications from Google (NO "Gmail", "Account Manager Google" and "Google Services Framework")
It looks as if not installed (or forbidden) Google applications from the producer.

Comment: Obviously the tablet wasn't certified with Google by the manufacturer, so you've got to flash the [Google Apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info) yourself if you want them. Or you use this big chance given to you (a Google free device), and install an open-source alternative like [miroG](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5a) :)

Comment: Thanks for comment. It is not for my needed but my company so i need stay with google. Can you post your comment as a answer so than i can mark it as answered?

Comment: There you go :) I've included some additional details and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manufacturers must certify their devices with Google in order to have the [Google Apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info) pre-installed<sup>1</sup>. Obviously that wasn't done for your device. So you have to either install GApps manually (follow the previous link for details) – or use the chance a "Google free" device gives you and install an open source alternative like [miroG](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5a).

---

<sup>**1:** See e.g. [here](http://www.theverge.com/2011/05/12/google-android-skyhook-lawsuit-motorola-samsung#1); the term for this agreement is [MADA](http://androidcommunity.com/googles-mada-defines-rules-for-android-device-makers-20140505/) (Mobile Application Distribution Agreement)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Izzy has already answered this, but adding this piece of information, so that you could authoritatively quote to your company

PDF at this link [List of all devices supported by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)
can be quoted after verifying if you can query with additional information on your device . Search based on details provided by you shows, it isn't registered